# How to delete stored session attributes in apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, session-variables

I have a web app and I'm using Apache Tomcat. I am getting an error about some session attributes that can't be serialized. I am not using this attributes anymore, but on deploy/redeploy I keep getting these errors. Are some part of these attributes still stored somewhere? If so, how can I delete them so I don't get the errors on console?

Comment: Do you have control of the code in the app? If so, why not stop storing these to the session?

Comment: @Darius I have already stopped storing these in the session, but it seems that there are still saved somewhere. When I redeploy the app it says that the attribute cant be serialized, even though I don't need it or use it anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using the manager webapp that comes with Tomcat? Hit: yourhost/manager/html and click on the session count, and then on one of the sessions, drilling down to see what is being stored

Comment: Couldn't find /manager/html. I deleted the whole project from Tomcat and built it again. The session attributes disappeared, so I don't have a problem anymore. I'm still curious about where exactly is the session information stored.

Comment: Typically, under your "webapps" directory, there should be a directory named "manager", but you may not have it in your installation.